# Text left justified/in the upper left corner?

Tags: text, xna

I wonder how I can set the position of my text to the upper left corner.
I don't want to declare exactly the pixels, because it's laborious and if someone use another resolution it's wrong.

Is there a simple way to get my problem solved?

Comment: Specifiing an exact position for left aligned text sounds perfectly reasonable to me. I cannot see the problem with a different resolution. It would be nice to have some more details or an image of the effect you want to achieve. And tell us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

The top left is always 0,0. It will never change regardless of resolution or the location of the xna window. Anyways you have to use pixels to set the location for anything drawn with the spritebatch, there is no other way to set location.

Comment: Ok, that's logical. Thank you.